# Cheap programmable drone, for use in the UK

Tags: drone, cheap

I am looking for a cheap, programmable drone, for use in UK, to use in a Minimal Viable Product for a system that will later use more highly spec’ed drones.

•   Needs to accept a programmed flight plan (*)
•   Needs to carry an ESP32 (approx. 10g) and a coin cell battery (2.9g), possibly an altimeter of GPS sensor (I would guess 5g, max 10g)
•   Long flight time is not important, but I would like 5, preferably 10 minutes
•   Outdoor use, not indoor, although I can live with being restricted to calm days

(*) I am not sure if UK law requires a human drone operator, rather than a programmed flight plan. If that’s the law, I will comply, but I have a strong preference for programming a series of waypoints.

---

[Update] do I need to be licensed to fly a drone in the UK?